# Using TimeZone with PipeDate in Angular 6 not working?

Tags: timezone, angular6, pipe

I am using DatePipe to display Epoch time, the milliseconds time is in UTC, I want to keep it display on UTC so I am setting timezone option is '0'.

Here is my code:

```
<span class="description">{{epochTime | date:'dd/MM/yy hh:mm a':'0'}}</span>
```

with '*epochTime*' = '1570274515223' <=> **'Sat Oct 05 2019 11:21:55 AM'**.
But on the UI is: ***'05/10/19 06:21 PM'***

It is getting local time zone here.  Why I can not force pipe to use UTC time?

Answer (score 0):

`'0'` is not valid.  Instead, specify the offset in one of the following ways: `0`, `'+0'`,`'+00:00'`, `'UTC'`

Comment: OK Matt, let me try.

Comment: I have tried in many ways:  > `<span class="description">{{model.createdOn|date:'dd/MM/yy hh:mm a': '+0'}}</span>`; `<span class="description">{{model.createdOn|date:'dd/MM/yy hh:mm a': 'UTC'}}</span>`; 
                      `<span class="description">{{model.createdOn|date:'dd/MM/yy hh:mm a': 0}}</span>`; 
                      `<span class="description">{{model.createdOn|date:'dd/MM/yy hh:mm a': '+00:00'}}</span>`;
But all is showing **05/10/19 06:21 PM**. My local machine timezone is UTC+7.

Comment: Is `model.createdOn` a string, a number, or a Date object?

Comment: It is a number of milliseconds. Like this: _createdOn: 1570274515223_